# How to Skip column "comments" while using mysqldump

Tags: php, web

I am using LAMP stack on Ubuntu. 
Using 'mysqldump' command to dump 'stack_db' into file.
While dumping a database to file I don't want column comments in dump.

I tried "--skip-comments and --compact options"

Looking for a solution to skip comments column fields while using mysqldump

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try your mysqldump statement as below:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -uroot -p ....
```

Or:

```
--skip-comments to skip comments
```